# Xcode Swift executable size much bigger than Objective-C executable

Tags: swift, xcode6

Executable size of Swift application is much bigger than size of Objective-C application.

For a new empty Cocoa Application project :

- in **Objective-C**, after build phase, I get a **65 Kb** executable
- in **Swift**, after build phase, I get a **4.2 Mb** executable, **66 times more** !!!

If I look at the generated package, there is a lot of frameworks included :

- libswiftAppKit.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib (**3.2Mb**),
  libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftDarwin.dylib,
  libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib,
  libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib,
  libswiftSecurity.dylib

I did not find project parameters to specify to include these libraries...

How is it that Swift executables are not build the same as in Objective-C ?

*Version of Xcode used : 6.1.1*

Comment: I had a look in my re-written (not completely identical) app and it increased from 2.3 to 9.3 MB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is to be expected.

For the time being, Swift itself lives in the binary of each application built with it. This may change when Swift reaches a release that Apple is comfortable bundling with iOS, but for now it's just something we have to live with. This behavior is the reason you can build an iOS 7/8 application in Swift 1.0/1.1/1.2 and it just works when you build and run.

You can find more info on this in [this article](http://blog.diogot.com/blog/2014/09/29/swift-embedded-runtime-library-increases-app-size/).

Comment: It's been more than 3 years, has this changed, is there now a way to create small Swift binaries? Thanks!

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Apple has added a build optimizing setting to optimize for binary size (set `-Osize` in your Swift optimization level settings to enable it), but unfortunately Swift is still going to be bundled with your apps. They currently plan to change this once Swift 5 is released, since this is when they're planning on achieving ABI stability by.